# Which of the two queries do I use best for performance?

Tags: mysql, performance

i have two query To do a job

query 1 :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 where id = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 where id = 70
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 where id = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 where id = 90
```

and query 2 :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where id IN (1,70,90)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 where id IN (5,3)
```

Which of these two queries is faster ?

If your answer is the second query .

I've used Query 1 in many different places. in the project Is the difference so large that I would replace everywhere with the second query ?

Comment: So why wouldn’t you just execute both queries and check which one is faster?

Comment: @emix Because I want to be explored conceptually, not at specific times

Comment: But this usually depends upon your table schema and the amount of data inside. Database settings also affect this, database version, engine used. There are so many factors. We cannot tell you how your database optimizer will perform due to this. Look how Tim responds: “should”, “assuming”, “might”.

Comment: @emix i use inodb engine and id is pk and on average tables has 300,000 rows

Comment: Next time just run your queries on a real dataset and check with EXPLAIN what decisions did the optimizer take.

Comment: Another variable... Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version is more concise, and should be faster, because it only requires actually executing two queries, as opposed to the first version, which does a separate query for each `id` value.

Assuming `id` be the primary key in both tables, then MySQL might also be able to use the clustered index for faster lookup of matching records.

Comment: I've used Query 1 in many different places. in the project Is the difference so large that I would replace everywhere with the second query ?

Comment: Doing a few unnecessary unions shouldn't kill your database performance, but best practice would be to refactor, assuming you are in a position to do that.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen Thanks for the description

Answer (score 0):

What are the typical counts?  Total of 5 rows?  2 tables?  I would predict the performance difference to be a factor of rows/tables in favoring the 2nd (shorter) formulation.  In experimenting, I got about 2x.

So, if you have 100 rows from 2 tables, the second formulation will be significantly faster; enough faster to be worth the effort.

Why?

- For such simple queries, parsing and optimizing dominates the time.
- For newer versions of MySQL, both queries will touch the same number of rows.
- For MySQL 5.7.3 and later, no temp table will be needed for either `UNION ALL`.

Does it matter that the output rows are likely to be in a different order?